# Signals not works? I want create profile instance when user was created

Tags: django

I read a part of the doc, and some articles, but my code is not working.

OBS: i'm using custom User created with AbstractUser, but i not add extra fields

Look this example

profile.signals.py:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from .models import Profile

User = get_user_model()

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

now, look in the user creation:

```
>>> from accounts.models import User
>>> me = User.objects.create(username='myusr', email='me@email.com', password='me123456')
>>> me
<User: myusr>
>>> me.save()
>>> me.profile
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/mnt/sda4/Development/coding/Projects/codesv3/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 415, in__get__
    self.related.get_accessor_name()
accounts.models.User.profile.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: User has no profile.
```

i dont know what's wrong. Also because I have not used it before and i not know about SQL triggers

Comment: have you added AUTH_USER_MODEL in settings?

Answer (score 1):

In your `signals.py` file, save `profile` after it's created, like below:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

Make sure, you `import signals` in your related `apps.py` file like below **example**:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'users'

    def ready(self):
        import users.signals
```

Then also make sure you have made the below change:

you must add `app's config` to either of two files.

In your `settings.py` file's `INSTALLED_APPS`, like mentioned in this link: [Django create profile for user signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61580144/django-create-profile-for-user-signal/65590029#65590029).

OR,

In your related `app`'s `__init__.py` file, like this (in this **example**, the related app is `users`): `default_app_config = 'users.apps.UsersConfig'`

Answer (score 0):

First, this command create user and you do not need to save it after creating:

```
me = User.objects.create(username='myusr', email='me@email.com', password='me123456')
```

Second, where your signals places? If you put it in models everything should works.
Also you can place where you want but you need to import it in your apps like here:

```
class ProfileConfig(BaseConfig):
    name = ...
    def ready():
        import profiles.signals # where your signals place
```