# django signals not creating user profile upon user creation

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a simple signal that creates a Profile object for a User after the user signs up a new account. What am I missing?

signals.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Profile
#from django_cleanup.signals import cleanup_pre_delete
#from sorl.thumbnail import delete

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance, bio="", linkedin_URL="", isCoach=False)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()

# def sorl_delete(**kwargs):
#     delete(kwargs['file'])

# cleanup_pre_delete.connect(sorl_delete)
```

apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class EventsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'events'

    def ready(self):
        import events.signals
```

Comment: is the app name "events"? i mean inside which app you are using singals.py ?

Comment: that's correct. The app 'events' contains the model.py that has the Profile model

Comment: Try `from . import signals`. Also you don't need two methods, remove the second one.

Comment: added that import and deleted the second method, didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometime the django signals just dont work when on seperate file try putting signals code on your models.py like this:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
#signals_section
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance, bio="", linkedin_URL="", isCoach=False)

def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()

post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
post_save.connect(save_profile, sender=User)
```

Comment: Why do you think this happens?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, you can add `app's config` to either of two files.

1. In your `settings.py` file's `INSTALLED_APPS`, like mentioned in this link:
   [Django create profile for user signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61580144/django-create-profile-for-user-signal/65590029#65590029)

OR,

2. In your related `app`'s `__init__.py` file, like this (in this example, the related app is `events`): `default_app_config = 'events.apps.EventsConfig'`